# Binding to a specific ip address when using the PHP mysql_connect function

Tags: php, mysql, linux, proxy, lamp

I have a Cent OS setup running a pretty standard LAMP stack and I have two publicly available IP addresses (eth0 and eth0:1).

I want to use the second IP address (eth0:1) when connecting out to a remotely hosted MySQL database.  How can I go about that?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. Do you want to bind your PHP scripts to a specific IP-address in such a way, that when requests come from the other, the script shouldn't be accessible?

Comment: I read it this way: While connecting to a mysql database server, a specific client network interface should be used to perform the connection. AFAIK `mysql_connect()` does not offer a parameter for this, so this might be a client-computer configuration issue.

Comment: Hakre is correct, that's what I am looking for.  Do you know of any common methods for working around the fact that mysql_connect doesn't support this?  I am not really sure what to look for but I was hoping I could, at the very least, proxy or provide some kind of rule for the port I am using to always communicate over eth0:1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have root access, you can do SNAT with iptables to use a specific source IP for this particular destination:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -d <mysql_server_ip> -j SNAT --to-source <source_ip>
```